# How do i migrate an app to iOS 5? (or turn on ARC)

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I've got an app i'm working on and i just started using iOS 5.  I'd like to start using Automatic Reference Counting but I'm not sure what steps i need to take to either migrate to iOS 5 or at least to turn on ARC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look in *Edit > Refactor* menu, you'll see an option called `Migrate to Objective-C ARC`.  That tool will help convert your code to ARC.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 docs are not publically viewable yet, but in your Xcode you can go to the Organizer and view documentation. Search for "Programming with ARC Release Notes" and there's a document in there which will hopefully answer most of the questions you have about the process.